# I am trying to create a program in which the computer picks a random number between 1 and 100 and tries to guess the number it picked

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, while-loop, conditional-statements

I am new to Python and I am just programming some random things for fun. I want to write a program in which the computer generates a random number between 1 and 100 and then tries to guess it. I do not want the user to interfere with it in any way. I also want to count how many guesses the computer took. I am also trying to have it run multiple times with a different number each time and calculate the average amount of guesses it took after those times. I know I need to incorporate a while loop, but I don't know how to have the computer keep guessing random numbers instead of just listing every number within the range and how do I tell it to stop? Do I need a for loop? Can someone help?

```
import random

the_num = random.randint(1, 100)
print('The number to guess is',the_num)
comp_guess = random.randint(1, 100)
print('The computer guesses ', comp_guess)
tries = 1

while comp_guess != the_num:
    print('The computer guesses ', comp_guess)
    tries = tries+1
    if comp_guess > the_num:
        comp_guess = comp_guess-1
    elif comp_guess < the_num:
        comp_guess = comp_guess+1
    elif comp_guess == the_num:
        break

print(tries)
print('The computer guessed it right!')
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what specific problem you're having because you've mentioned so many things you "want" to do. Please edit your question to be one specific problem you're having. See [ask] a question for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Minor change: once the computer fails to guess it needs to keep guessing, since the following line is not in the (while) loop it doesn't happen:

```
comp_guess = random.randint(1, 100)
```

the fix is easy (see code-comment below):

```
import random

the_num = random.randint(1, 100)
print('The number to guess is',the_num)
comp_guess = random.randint(1, 100)
print('The computer guesses ', comp_guess)
tries = 1

while comp_guess != the_num:
    print('The computer guesses ', comp_guess)
    tries += 1
    if comp_guess == the_num:
        break
    else:     # if the computer didn't guess it, guess again!
        comp_guess = random.randint(1, 100)

print(tries)
print('The computer guessed it right!')
```

Now, if you want to repeat this whole logic a few times, stick it in a function and call it in a loop:

```
import random


def guess():
    the_num = random.randint(1, 100)
    print('The number to guess is',the_num)
    comp_guess = random.randint(1, 100)
    print('The computer guesses ', comp_guess)
    tries = 1

    while comp_guess != the_num:
        print('The computer guesses ', comp_guess)
        tries += 1
        if comp_guess == the_num:
            break
        else:
            comp_guess = random.randint(1, 100)

    print(tries)
    print('The computer guessed it right!')


for i in range(5):
    guess()
```